# WPF ContextMenu Click event is triggered only after MouseMove event of the background grid

Tags: c#, wpf, contextmenu, mahapps.metro

I have grid. In it, I open a ContextMenu. When I click a MenuItem, the following happens in order: (1) the grid's MouseMove event is triggered; (2) the MenuItem's Click event is triggered; and, finally, (3) the menu closes.

I expect events (2) and (3) to happen before (1). Why is this happening? Is there any way for the menu to "block" background events until it closes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order in which events are triggered in a user interface framework like WinForms or WPF can sometimes be unexpected, especially when you have events from different controls interacting with each other. In this case, it's not that the menu "blocks" background events until it closes, but rather that the event handling mechanism of the framework may be causing the events to be processed in a specific order.

The order of event processing in a typical Windows Forms (WinForms) application is as follows:

MouseDown
MouseUp
Click (if MouseDown and MouseUp occurred in the same control)
MouseMove
In your scenario, when you open a context menu and click a MenuItem, the MouseMove event may get triggered before the MenuItem's Click event because the mouse button was pressed down, then released when you clicked the MenuItem. This sequence follows the typical event order.

There isn't a built-in way to easily change the order in which events are processed by the framework. However, you can work around this issue by setting a flag when the context menu is opened and clearing it when it's closed. In your MouseMove event handler, you can check this flag to determine if the event should be processed or ignored while the menu is open.

Here's a simplified example in C#:

```
 private bool contextMenuOpen = false;

    private void contextMenu_Opening(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        contextMenuOpen = true;
    }

private void contextMenu_Closed(object sender, ToolStripDropDownClosedEventArgs e)
{
    contextMenuOpen = false;
}

private void grid_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (contextMenuOpen)
    {
        // Ignore MouseMove events while the context menu is open.
        return;
    }

    // Your MouseMove event handling code here.
}

private void menuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Handle the MenuItem's Click event.
}
private bool contextMenuOpen = false;

private void contextMenu_Opening(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    contextMenuOpen = true;
}

private void contextMenu_Closed(object sender, ToolStripDropDownClosedEventArgs e)
{
    contextMenuOpen = false;
}

private void grid_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (contextMenuOpen)
    {
        // Ignore MouseMove events while the context menu is open.
        return;
    }

    // Your MouseMove event handling code here.
}

private void menuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Handle the MenuItem's Click event.
}
```

In this example, when the context menu is opened, the contextMenuOpen flag is set to true, and it's cleared when the menu is closed. In the grid_MouseMove event handler, we check the flag and avoid processing the event if the context menu is open.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I understand that there is an order to events, however, I don't understand why this background event is triggered in the first place. I mean, if I were to click a button inside a grid, since the button is hit testable and has a background, clicking on it would not trigger its parent grid's mouse move event. Why would this be different for a ContextMenu?

I thought about using a flag, however, this does prevent the mouse move event from being triggered after the menu closes. That is, the user must move the mouse before they see any reaction.

Using WPF btw.

Comment: Regarding my last comment, apparently, I was wrong. The MouseMove event is actually triggered twice. So the order of events is I click the MenuItem, MouseMove, Click event, MouseMove, menu closes. So I guess the flag is an acceptable workaround. However, I still don't understand why this happens. (I.e., why the menu does not block background events as long as it is open.)

Comment: In WPF, events are categorized into two types: tunneling and bubbling events. Tunneling events occur on the way down the visual tree, while bubbling events occur on the way up. The MouseMove event is a bubbling event, which means it propagates up the visual tree to find handlers. In the case of the MenuItem click, the bubbling MouseMove event is raised both before and after the MenuItem click event because the MouseMove event is part of the bubbling route.

Comment: The reason behind this behavior is that WPF allows multiple controls to potentially handle the same event, and events like MouseMove are not automatically suppressed by child controls during a specific interaction, such as clicking a MenuItem. Instead, the event propagates through the visual tree.

Comment: The ContextMenu does not inherently block or suppress background events; it's up to the individual controls to handle events or not during specific interactions. In your case, the use of a flag is a reasonable workaround to control the event handling, but it does come with the trade-off you mentioned where there's a small delay in the mouse response after the menu closes.

Comment: To summarize, the behavior you're observing is a result of the event routing mechanism in WPF, and it's not specific to ContextMenu. If you want to have more fine-grained control over event handling, you'll need to use flags or other mechanisms as you've described to ensure that events are processed in the desired order or suppressed during certain interactions.  I tried to explain it as far as I knew enough. I hope I was able to help a little bit.

Comment: I appreciate your thorough explanations! Ended up using the workaround we discussed. It still does not make 100% sense to me why this works like this (i.e., why they chose this design). In my mind, a context menu should be "above" all its background elements. But I understand how it works now. (And that it's not some issue with my code.) Also not sure why I'm being downvoted...